# How to efficiently return multiple DriverResults from the Display method?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

[This article](http://arkleseizure.net/making-your-driver-display-methods-perform-better) describes how to write efficient DisplayDrivers for your Parts so that expensive code is only executed when the shape is actually displayed.

```cs
protected override DriverResult Display(MyPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    // return the shape
    return ContentShape("Parts_MyPart", () => {
        // do computations here
        return shapeHelper.Parts_MyPart();
    });
}
```

Now I'd like to make a Part that returns multiple DriverResults using the `Combine` method, with each DriverResult containing mostly the same data, which is fetched from the database. The problem is I can't think of a good way to make it efficient, since `Combine` doesn't take a Func parameter.

```cs
protected override DriverResult Display(MyPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    var data = ... // expensive query specific to the part

    return Combined(
       ContentShape("Parts_MyPart_A", () => shapeHelper.Parts_MyPart_A(
            Data: data
        )),
        ContentShape("Parts_MyPart_B", () => shapeHelper.Parts_MyPart_B(
            Data: data
        )),
        ContentShape("Pars_MyPart_C", ...
    );
}
```

Can I achieve the same result so that the query is not executed if nothing is displayed and only executed once if multiple shapes are displayed?

I want to do this so I can display the same data on a ContentItem's Detail in different zones with different markup and styling. An alternative approach could be to return one shape that in turn pushes other shapes into different zones but then I would lose the ability to use Placement to control each of them individually.

Comment: And keep those drivers efficient! http://arkleseizure.net/dont-let-the-designer-ruin-your-drivers-performance

Comment: You could use a backing field, create a method that checks if the backing field is not null, then returns it, else it triggers the expensive query and set it on the backing field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably add a lazy field to your Part.

```
public class MyPart : ContentPart {
    internal readonly LazyField<CustomData> CustomDataField = new LazyField<CustomData>();

    public CustomData CustomData {
      get { return CustomDataField.Value; }
    }
}

public class CustomData {
    ...
}

public class MyPartHandler : ContentPartHandler {

   private ICustomService _customService;

   public MyPartHandler(ICustomService customService){
      _customService = customService;
      OnActivated<MyPart>(Initialize);
   }

   private void Initialize(ActivatedContentContext context, MyPart part){
         part.CustomDataField.Loader(() => {
             return _customService.Get(part.ContentItem.Id);
         });
   }
}
```

It will only be calculated if it is loaded and all the shapes will share the calculated value.

Comment: I immediately applied this principle in several places and it massively improved my average performance. Excellent solution.